# repaint()を記述してもpaintComponent()が呼び出されません…

Tags: java, swing

swingを使って簡単なゲームを作っているのですが、描画処理がどうもうまくいかなくて困っています。。。

並列処理を使ってコンポーネントをひたすらrepaintし続ける処理を書いたつもりなんですが、いろいろいじったりして何度試してみても一向にpaintComponent()が呼び出されません。

原因が分かる方がいれば、ぜひご教授願いたいです…

---

PlayView.java（一部抜粋）

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.swing.*;

public class PlayView extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable{

    public JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //全部のコンポ―ネントを乗せるJPanel
    public static JPanel[] lane = new JPanel[4];
    public JLabel[] judge = new JLabel[4];
    public JLabel combo = new JLabel();
    public Dimension panelsize = null;

public PlayView() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
            lane[i] = new JPanel();
            judge[i] = new JLabel();
        }

        panel.setSize(800, 600);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //座標指定でコンポーネントを配置
            lane[i].setBounds(200 * i, 0, 200, 500);
            judge[i].setBounds(200 * i, 520, 200, 60);
            lane[i].setBackground(new Color(211,211,211));
            lane[i].setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
            judge[i].setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
            judge[i].setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,27));
            judge[i].setForeground(new Color(220,20,60));
            panel.add(lane[i]);
            panel.add(judge[i]);
        }

        this.panelsize = lane[0].getSize();

        panel.setBackground(new Color(135,206,235));
        panel.addKeyListener(this);

    }

@Override
    public void run() {
        while (this.isVisible())  {
            panel.repaint();　//10msごとにpanelの再描画
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //System.out.println("paintComponent");
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(new Color(255, 255, 255));//211,211,211
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            g.fillRect(200 * i, 0, (int) this.panelsize.getWidth(), (int) this.panelsize.getHeight());
        }
        //座標をランダムに変えて画像を描画
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
　　　　　  g.drawImage((new ImageIcon("hoge.png")).getImage(), (int)Math.random() * (int) this.panelsize.getWidth(), 
           (int)Math.random() * (int) this.panelsize.getHeight(), lane[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) { //spaceを押したらrun()呼び出し
          Thread thread = new Thread(this);
          thread.start(); //this.run()の中身実行？
    }
}
```

MainFrame.java

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
    PlayView pv = new PlayView();
    public MainFrame() {
        this.add(pv.panel);
        pv.panel.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(200, 100, 800, 600);
        this.addKeyListener(pv);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame f = new MainFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### 動くコード

**MainFrame.java**

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    PlayView pv = new PlayView();
    public MainFrame() {
        this.add(pv.panel);
        pv.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(200, 100, 800, 600);
        this.addKeyListener(pv);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame f = new MainFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**PlayView.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class PlayView extends JPanel implements KeyListener, Runnable {

    //public JPanel panel = this; //解法その2
    public JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //解法その1
    public static JPanel[] lane = new JPanel[4];
    public JLabel[] judge = new JLabel[4];
    public JLabel combo = new JLabel();
    public Dimension panelsize = null;

    public PlayView() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            lane[i] = new JPanel() {
                @Override
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                    Image img = new ImageIcon("hoge.png").getImage();
                    int x = (int)(Math.random() * getWidth());
                    int y = (int)(Math.random() * getHeight());
                    g.drawImage(img, x, y, img.getWidth(this), img.getHeight(this), this);
                }
            };
            judge[i] = new JLabel();
        }

        panel.setSize(800, 600);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { //座標指定でコンポーネントを配置
            lane[i].setBounds(200 * i, 0, 200, 500);
            judge[i].setBounds(200 * i, 520, 200, 60);
            lane[i].setBackground(new Color(211, 211, 211));
            lane[i].setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
            judge[i].setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
            judge[i].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 27));
            judge[i].setForeground(new Color(220, 20, 60));
            panel.add(lane[i]);
            panel.add(judge[i]);
        }

        this.panelsize = lane[0].getSize();

        panel.setBackground(new Color(135, 206, 235));
        panel.addKeyListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (this.isVisible()) {
            //repaint();  //解法その2
            panel.repaint();  //解法その1
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) { //spaceを押したらrun()呼び出し
            Thread thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start(); //this.run()の中身実行？
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke) {}
}
```

#### 修正点

1. `PlayView#run`メソッドで**PlayViewではなくpanelを**`repaint`する
2. `lane`インスタンスに`repaint`を実装
3. 全角スペースを半角スペースに変換
4. 足りないimportを補完

#### ポイント

1. `PlayView`クラスは`JPanel`を継承していますが、`JPanel`として描画されません。
   中に入っている`panel`がその役目を担っていますので、`repaint`する対象を`panel`に書き換えると`paintComponent`が呼び出されます。
2. `PlayView`クラスを`JPanel`として使う場合は、サンプルコードの解法その1を削除して解法その2のコメントを削除してみてください。
3. `panel`の上に`lane`が乗っているので、その下に隠れている`panel`を描画しても隠れていて動きません。
   どの`lane`に何を描画するか細かく制御したい場合は、`lane`クラスを`JPanel`ではなく`LanePanel extends JPanel`などの別クラスとして定義して、`PlayView`とパラメータを受け渡しすることをご検討ください。